# Bash Copy multiple lines in seperate files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gentoo

i have one file with follow entries, is very long so show few examples:

```
    media-libs/gd fontconfig xpm
    media-sound/audacious -gtk gtk3
    net-analyzer/wireshark -gtk3 -ssl -qt4 qt5 lua geoip kerberos adns
    net-dialup/ppp -gtk
```

I need to copy every line in a new file called like the name between / and first spaces.

So that i have a file called gd, audacious, wireshark and ppp with appropriate content behind name.

```
    media-libs/gd fontconfig xpm
    media-sound/audacious -gtk gtk3
    net-analyzer/wireshark -gtk3 -ssl -qt4 qt5 lua geoip kerberos adns
    net-dialup/ppp -gtk
```

Thank you for help & wish nice weekend

Silvio

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this, but please try it in a separate directory where you just have a COPY of your data:

```
awk '{f=$1;sub(/.*\//,"",f);print > f}' yourFile
```

It may not be that robust, but it takes the first field of each line, strips everything up to a slash and saves that as `f`, then writes the whole line to file `f`.

Comment: Thank you, works perfekt. A short line and i try since hours.

Comment: A little simpler is to use the `-F` option to split each line into appropriate fields, rather than use the `sub` function: `awk -F'/| ' '{print > $2}'`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you, yes, that is a possibility but I wasn't sure if there may be multiple slashes which would move the field numbers along.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to loop with a while loop, you can look at:

```
while read -r line; do
        echo "line=${line}"
        noSlash=${line##*/}
        echo "noSlash=${noSlash}"
        filename=${noSlash%% *}
        echo "filename=${filename}"
        content=${noSlash#* }
        echo "Content=${content}"
done < input
```

The input file at the last line of the code is parsed 1 line each time. The variables are parsed using `#` and `%`. The result is echoed in the above code for testing. WHen you are happy with the solution, you can use

```
while read -r line; do
        noSlash=${line##*/}
        filename=${noSlash%% *}
        content=${noSlash#* }
        printf "%s\n" "${content}" > "${filename}"
done < input
```